# Divide two values from same column and then show only values between 0 and 3

Tags: sql

I am not sure if this is even possible but I am trying to filter "results" after dividing two values from the same column (which already works).

```
SELECT
  "Business Name",
  (sum(CASE
       WHEN "Source Indicator" = 'Month end cash balance'
         THEN "EUR AMOUNT"
       END) / sum(CASE
                  WHEN "Source Indicator" = 'Total OPEX'
                    THEN "EUR AMOUNT"
                  END)) AS "Run Rate"
FROM "Steering_database_eur"
WHERE MONTH("End Date") = (MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1)
GROUP BY "Business Name"
```

Now all I need is to show only values between -10 and 3 in the "Run Rate" column.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after:

```
SELECT
         "Business Name",
         (sum(case
                 when "Source Indicator"  = 'Month end cash balance' then "EUR AMOUNT"
             end) / sum(case
                 when "Source Indicator"  = 'Total OPEX' then "EUR AMOUNT"
             end)) as "Run Rate"
FROM  "Steering_database_eur" 
WHERE    MONTH("End Date")  = (MONTH(GETDATE()) -1)
GROUP BY  "Business Name" 
HAVING  (sum(case
                 when "Source Indicator"  = 'Month end cash balance' then "EUR AMOUNT"
             end) / sum(case
                 when "Source Indicator"  = 'Total OPEX' then "EUR AMOUNT"
             end)) BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

        --your query here
)t
WHERE [Run Rate] BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```

Comment: This one did now work for me, maybe I did something wrong but it gives an error that "Run Rate" is invalid column.

Comment: Have you tried exact same as above : Just Updated RunRate with` [Run Rate]`

Comment: Yes, i tried with the exact format, except that columns are written with " " where I am using the code (Zoho Reports).